# RLMObject subclasses with the same name cannot be included twice in the same target

Tags: ios, realm

I'm having issues with testing Realm. If I do include my object files into test target, I get this error when performing tests:

```
   file:///path/project-iOS/project-iOS/DataManager.m: test failure: -
    [SingleHouseDb_Test testPerformanceExample] failed: failed: caught
     "RLMException", "RLMObject subclasses with the same name cannot be
     included twice in the same target. Please make sure 'StringObject' is only linked
     once to your current target."
```

But if I remove the files from the target it fails to build at all!

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DVMap", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DVHouse", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DVReport", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
          objc-class-ref in ReportsViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DVReportPhoto", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DVUserProfile", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
          objc-class-ref in ReportsViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_StringObject", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in DataManager.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'my-iOS' do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Realm'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
end

target 'my-iOSTests', exclusive: true do
    pod 'Realm/Headers'
end

target 'my-iOSUITests', exclusive: true do
    pod 'Realm/Headers'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, [@marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4194189/marius) answer helped, but I managed to resolve it myself. I had it all mixed up, maybe this will help someone else.

1. All your `.m` files should only be in your main app target, not in test targets
2. Use following `podfile` structure:

```rb
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'myPoject-iOS' do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Realm'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
end

target 'myPoject-iOSTests', exclusive: true do
    pod 'Realm/Headers'
end

target 'myPoject-iOSUITests', exclusive: true do
    pod 'Realm/Headers'
end
```

After this everything should work.

If you have any Swift files, like I do, it gets tricker. It tells that `someheader-Swift.h` not found. It is autogenerated file that has its own name for each target. So you need to remove all references to it, and instead use that header in precompiled headers, like so:

1. Do everything from above
2. For your swift files, add files to all targets
3. If you have a precompiled header, use it, or create new one. Use something like this:

```
#if MAIN_TARGET==1
#import "myProject-Swift.h"
#elif TESTS_TARGET==1
#import "myProject_iOSTests-Swift.h"
#elif UI_TESTS_TARGET==1
#import "myProject_iOSUITests-Swift.h"
#endif
```

You need the linker/compiler to use the correct file on each target. For this you need to add some defines/macros to `Build Settings - Preprocessor Macros` to each target. For example add `MAIN_TARGET=1` to your main target.

This has helped me.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different approaches to testing for iOS.
**Application Tests** and **Logic Tests**. Both have different implications on how you setup your targets. You can't mix them, you have to decide for one paradigm of both. As you use frameworks and Realm you have to use the former.

### Application Tests

They are usually linked against your app (identified by the build setting `BUNDLE_LOADER`) if it was a dynamic library it would been linked to. On runtime, they load a test host (`TEST_HOST`), which is usually your app executable which starts in the simulator first. They inject the built test bundle by `dyld`, so that you can use effectively every symbol, which is used within your app transitively. That's nowadays the default setup if you setup a new test target in Xcode.

#### Target Memberships

To follow this approach, you **must not share target memberships** of your app target's code with your test target. But you need to make sure that all your model files are still members of your app target.

So the target memberships for a file `Object.swift` might look like below:

[image: Target Membership App Only]

*Alternatively* like that:

[image: Target Membership Framework Only]

#### CocoaPods

With CocoaPods, your Podfile should look like that:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'my-iOS' do
    link_to 'my-iOS', 'my-iOSTests', 'my-iOSUITests'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Realm'
    pod 'SDWebImage'    
end
```

The header subspec is intended for the **Logic Tests** approach when using static linking.

Please also take a look at the Realm documentation's chapter about [Avoid Linking Realm and Tested Code in Test Targets](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#avoid-linking-realm-and-tested-code-in-test-targets).

Comment: If a class (which is defined in say, Example) is not a member of the test target (ExampleTests) build will fail when testing because the class will not be found.